# I want my code to check multiple conditions and pick the one that has been met and execute it. Unfortunately my code is not returning anything

Tags: python-3.x, function, if-statement, tkinter, conditional-statements

**corr** is the correlation coeficient value, meaning I have 3 correlation values and **std_mev** are standard deviation value meaning I also have 3 standard deviation values. I want my code to check if the conditions in the code below are met and if they are met it should execute the statement that is true and compute the **induc** values as shown in the code. Unfortunately no error or even an execution is being performed to produce the **induc values** please assist, I have a attached a picture to show this[image]. the code is below:

```
    corr1,_ = pearsonr(list_losses, list_mev1)
    print('Pearsons correlation[loss and MEV1]: %.4f' % corr1)

    corr2,_ = pearsonr(list_losses, list_mev2)
    print('Pearsons correlation[loss and MEV2]: %.4f' % corr2)

    corr3,_ = pearsonr(list_losses, list_mev3)
    print('Pearsons correlation[loss and MEV3]: %.4f' % corr3)

    ### calculating standard deviation
    std_mev1 = statistics.stdev(std_mev1_list)
    std_mev2 = statistics.stdev(std_mev2_list)
    std_mev3 = statistics.stdev(std_mev3_list)

    print("Std MEV 1 = ",std_mev1)
    print("Std MEV 1 = ",std_mev2)
    print("Std MEV 1 = ",std_mev3)

    if corr1>=0.5 and corr2>=0.5 and corr3>=0.5:
        induc_cur_ls = cur_ls*(1+std_mev1)*(1+std_mev2)*(1+std_mev3)
        induc_on2_ls = on2_ls*(1+std_mev1)*(1+std_mev2)*(1+std_mev3)
        induc_tt2_ls = tt2_ls*(1+std_mev1)*(1+std_mev2)*(1+std_mev3)
        induc_sx2_ls = sx2_ls*(1+std_mev1)*(1+std_mev2)*(1+std_mev3)
        induc_nn2_ls = nn2_ls*(1+std_mev1)*(1+std_mev2)*(1+std_mev3)
    elif corr1>=0.5 and corr2>=0.5 and corr3<0.5:
        induc_cur_ls = cur_ls*(1+std_mev1)*(1+std_mev2)
        induc_on2_ls = on2_ls*(1+std_mev1)*(1+std_mev2)
        induc_tt2_ls = tt2_ls*(1+std_mev1)*(1+std_mev2)
        induc_sx2_ls = sx2_ls*(1+std_mev1)*(1+std_mev2)
        induc_nn2_ls = nn2_ls*(1+std_mev1)*(1+std_mev2)
    elif corr1>=0.5 and corr3>=0.5 and corr2<0.5:
        induc_cur_ls = cur_ls*(1+std_mev1)*(1+std_mev3)
        induc_on2_ls = on2_ls*(1+std_mev1)*(1+std_mev3)
        induc_tt2_ls = tt2_ls*(1+std_mev1)*(1+std_mev3)
        induc_sx2_ls = sx2_ls*(1+std_mev1)*(1+std_mev3)
        induc_nn2_ls = nn2_ls*(1+std_mev1)*(1+std_mev3)
    elif corr3>=0.5 and corr2>=0.5 and corr1<0.5:
        induc_cur_ls = cur_ls*(1+std_mev2)*(1+std_mev3)
        induc_on2_ls = on2_ls*(1+std_mev2)*(1+std_mev3)
        induc_tt2_ls = tt2_ls*(1+std_mev2)*(1+std_mev3)
        induc_sx2_ls = sx2_ls*(1+std_mev2)*(1+std_mev3)
        induc_nn2_ls = nn2_ls*(1+std_mev2)*(1+std_mev3)
    elif corr1>=0.5 and corr2<0.5 and corr3<0.5:
        induc_cur_ls = cur_ls*(1+std_mev1)
        induc_on2_ls = on2_ls*(1+std_mev1)
        induc_tt2_ls = tt2_ls*(1+std_mev1)
        induc_sx2_ls = sx2_ls*(1+std_mev1)
        induc_nn2_ls = nn2_ls*(1+std_mev1)
    elif corr2>=0.5 and corr1<0.5 and corr3<0.5:
        induc_cur_ls = cur_ls*(1+std_mev2)
        induc_on2_ls = on2_ls*(1+std_mev2)
        induc_tt2_ls = tt2_ls*(1+std_mev2)
        induc_sx2_ls = sx2_ls*(1+std_mev2)
        induc_nn2_ls = nn2_ls*(1+std_mev2)
    elif corr3>=0.5 and corr1<0.5 and corr2<0.5:
        induc_cur_ls = cur_ls*(1+std_mev3)
        induc_on2_ls = on2_ls*(1+std_mev3)
        induc_tt2_ls = tt2_ls*(1+std_mev3)
        induc_sx2_ls = sx2_ls*(1+std_mev3)
        induc_nn2_ls = nn2_ls*(1+std_mev3)
    else:
        induc_cur_ls = cur_ls
        induc_on2_ls = on2_ls
        induc_tt2_ls = tt2_ls
        induc_sx2_ls = sx2_ls
        induc_nn2_ls = nn2_ls

        print(induc_cur_ls)
        print(induc_on2_ls)
        print(induc_tt2_ls)
        print(induc_sx2_ls)
        print(induc_nn2_ls)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While this is not an answer (I think @abdullatif has given you one), I think it is a simplification of the code you should consider. Of course, check it to make sure it does what you wanted to do, but I think it does.

```
corr1_multiplier = (1 + std_mev1) if corr1 >= 0.5 else 1.0
corr2_multiplier = (1 + std_mev2) if corr2 >= 0.5 else 1.0
corr3_multiplier = (1 + std_mev3) if corr3 >= 0.5 else 1.0
corr_multiplier = corr1_multiplier * corr2_multiplier * corr3_multiplier

induc_cur_ls = cur_ls * corr_multiplier
induc_on2_ls = on2_ls * corr_multiplier
induc_tt2_ls = tt2_ls * corr_multiplier
induc_sx2_ls = sx2_ls * corr_multiplier
induc_nn2_ls = nn2_ls * corr_multiplier
```

Answer (score 1):

Everything seems correct, but the print in the last few lines are inside the else condition which is not executed. that's why your code doesn't print anything. Try to indent them back to be outside the condition like this:

```
    else:
        induc_cur_ls = cur_ls
        induc_on2_ls = on2_ls
        induc_tt2_ls = tt2_ls
        induc_sx2_ls = sx2_ls
        induc_nn2_ls = nn2_ls

    print(induc_cur_ls)
    print(induc_on2_ls)
    print(induc_tt2_ls)
    print(induc_sx2_ls)
    print(induc_nn2_ls)
```